# Nginx (Build From Source) On Ubuntu 14.04 x64?

Tags: nginx, compilation, spdy, mod-pagespeed

I am a newB to setting up NGINX from source and every .sh configuration I try has errors of some type - I have been at this for days! - LOL

I am needing a set up with pageSpeed, OppenSSL, SPDY and Naxsi mods at minimum to drive an equal amount of static and dynamically php files on the site.

Below is my latest attempt that I put together but I get "*.configure command not found*" :P

If anyone can go thru it ( I am not sure about the dependencies either) and see what I have wrong??  Also any suggestions would also be greatly appreciated. Thnx!

```
# Since I am not going to be using a distribution to install Nginx,
# I need to ensure all the necessary dependencies are installed for it
# as well as for PageSpeed and SPDY:
sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libbz2-dev libssl-dev tar unzip openssl

# create a directory root directory called src to download all the filles to,
# including Nginx:
sudo mkdir src
cd src

# NGINX
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.7.4.tar.gz
tar -xvzf nginx-1.7.4.tar.gz

# Google PageSpeed:
wget https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/archive/release-1.8.31.4-beta.zip
unzip release-1.8.31.4-beta.zip
cd ngx_pagespeed-release-1.8.31.4-beta/
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/page-speed/psol/1.8.31.4.tar.gz
sudo tar -xzvf 1.8.31.4.tar.gz

# Switch back to src directory
cd
cd src

# HTTP Substitutions Module:
wget https://github.com/arut/nginx-dav-ext-module/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip

# Now let’s grab the Headers More Mod:
wget https://github.com/agentzh/headers-more-nginx-module/archive/v0.25.tar.gz
tar -xvzf v0.25.tar.gz

# and the naxsi module:
wget https://github.com/nbs-system/naxsi/archive/0.53-2.tar.gz
tar -xvzf 0.53-2.tar.gz

# cd to the uncompresses Nginx directory
cd
cd nginx-1.7.4


# Run a .configure command:
.configure \
--add-module=/src/naxsi-0.53-2 \
--prefix=/usr/share/nginx \
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--user=www-data \
--group=www-data \
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body \
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy \
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi \
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi \
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock \
--pid-path=/run/nginx.pid \
--with-pcre-jit \
--with-debug \
--with-http_addition_module \
--with-http_dav_module \
--with-http_geoip_module \
--with-http_gzip_static_module \
--with-http_image_filter_module \
--with-http_realip_module \
--with-http_stub_status_module \
--with-http_ssl_module \
--with-http_sub_module \
--with-http_xslt_module \
--with-ipv6 \
--with-http_spdy_module \
--add-module=/src/nginx-dav-ext-module-master \
--add-module=/src/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module \
--add-module=/src/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.8.31.4-beta \
--add-module=/src/headers-more-nginx-module-0.25

# Now create the Makefile:
make
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's not a typo? It should be ./configure (not .configure).

Comment: Thnx - I actually caught that b4 coming here for the answer.